# Minimal polynomial for diagonalizable operators

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed $n\times n$ matrix. Let $T$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $T(B)= AB$. How to show that the minimal polynomial for $T$ is the minimal polynomial for $A$? I have no idea!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Find", "Show") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.(AM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $T^i(B) = A^iB$. If $f(t)=a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_mt^m$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then $f(A) = a_0I + a_1A+\cdots + a_mA^m = \mathbf{0}$.

Now, $f(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ if and only if $f(T)$ is the zero transformation on $V$, and for every $g(t)$, if $g(T)$ is the zero transformation, then $f(t)|g(t)$.

For the first, what is $f(T)$? Well, if we evaluate it at $B$ we get
$$\begin{align*}
f(T)(B) &= \Bigl( a_0\mathrm{Id} + a_1T+\cdots a_mT^m\Bigr)(B)\\
&= a_0B + a_1T(B) +\cdots + a_mT^m(B)\\
&= a_0B + a_1AB + \cdots + a_mA^mB\\
&= (a_0I + a_1A+\cdots + a_mA^m)(B).
\end{align*}$$
Do we know how much that is?

Now if $g(T)$ is the zero linear transformation, then in particular $g(T)(I_n)=\mathbf{0}$. What does that tell you about $g(A)$? What does that tell you about the relationship between $f(t)$ and $g(t)$?

Comment: thanks very much Sir! for wonderful answer. I am greatly indebted to you. thanks once again.